# Find integral of (Im$z$)$^2$ over unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration

So Im$z$ = $\sin t$ and thus (Im$z$)$^2$ is $\sin^2t$

so my integral becomes (over the unit circle $e^{it}$)

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin^2t \cdot i e^{it} dt&= i\int_0^{2 \pi}(\frac{1}{2i}(e^{it}-e^{-it}))^2 e^{it} dt\\
&=-\frac{i}{4} \int_0^{2 \pi} e^{3 i t}-2e^{it}+e^{-it}dt\\
&=0
\end{align}

Did I do this correctly? The Last equality holds as

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} Ae^{int}dt=0$$ for any choice of $A \in \Bbb{R}$ or $n \in \Bbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, this is true, no? I tried proving it and it works out!

Comment: Yes.  You are correct!

Comment: Minor nitpick: if $A$ is not zero and $n$ is zero then your final equation is false

Comment: good catch! @FShrike

Comment: Note that the $(\rm{Im}z)^2$ isn't analytic.  Thus we see that the converse to Cauchy's theorem is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, your answer is right, or you can think like this: $z=x+iy$ and $Imz=y$, the integral becomes $\int\limits_{unit \ circle} (Imz)^2 dz=\int\limits_{unit \ circle} y^2 dz$ and the integral is $0$ for the symmetric.

Comment: Thanks! Someone answered saying the result is $\pi$ which threw me off